# Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined node.js discord.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, discord.js, emoji

The code below worked flawlessly a week ago ago (before Discord went down for a few hours just a few days ago? might be irrelevant). I haven't touched it since I got the code working. Now, the code results in an error code of "(node:5084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined"

I have tried looking up any updates that might have been made to node.js, discord.js, discord itself, etc... nothing I saw seemed to explain why my code all of a sudden stopped working.

I have also updated VSC, node.js, discord.js and discord itself.

```js
async function QuestionDeckToEdit(){

    if (decknames.length == 1){
        let msg = await message.author.send(`You have only one deck currently. Select the #1 below to progress with editing ${decknames[0]}.`)
        await msg.react(reaction_numbers[1])

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return [reaction_numbers[1], reaction_numbers[2], reaction_numbers[3]].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };

        const reply = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
            .catch(console.error);

        const targetDeck = reply.first()
        return targetDeck
    ...
    }
}

(async function(){
    let targetDeck = await QuestionDeckToEdit();

    if (targetDeck.emoji.name == reaction_numbers[1]){ //<<< Error comes from this line.
        var deckname = decknames[0]
        var userDeck = cardsInDeck[0]
        var userBakugan = bakuganKit[0]
        var userBakuCores = coresForKit[0]

    ...
    })();
})
})
```

The code above has some sections removed, but basically the bot asks for which kit the person would like to view and sends the info to them based on what emoji was used. It worked perfect a week ago. Proof of such here: https://i.gyazo.com/e51a4eb265069df268244c85f6df314a.png

I am just at a loss as to what might have changed to make this not work all of a sudden. This same problem is happening across multiple commands I made about a  week ago as well, same error code on each one involving essentially the same line.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(reply)` in `QuestionDeckToEdit()`? The error is telling you that `targetDeck` is undefined, so backtracking will help identify what's going awry.

Comment: @slothiful It doesn't even seem to get there. The error somehow occurs before the console.log(reply) line. It is like it ignores the await QuestionDeckToEdit() line entirely. It is almost like it is acting as synchronously instead of async... I just don't see how it changed all of a sudden.

Comment: What's `decknames.length`? That may be why it isn't returning anything, since it wouldn't be triggering the `if` statement.

Comment: @slothiful It can't even tell me that. decknames.length was reading the amount of decks the person has created in the mysql table. I know that number was correctly working. The error occurs almost instantly, so I can't provide much more than that. The question about which kit to view doesn't even occur.

Comment: I'm honestly kind of lost here. I think some more context within the code may help. I'd suggest some basic debugging, by printing to the console each time a certain piece of code is called.

Comment: Calling the decknames.length should be the very first thing. Not much happens before that. I'm not sure what is going on either. It is happening beyond just this command though. It is happening in other commands that once worked flawlessly too. I'm not sure it is this command exclusive.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help. Make sure to include needed context, but narrow it down to specifically where the issue seems to arise from.

Comment: I feel like a fool.... I didn't realize the entries in my database of decks was cleaned out, so it tried to find a deck in which none existed. -_- Needless to say, I've added a result for when no decks exist instead of 1 or more. I feel stupid.... lol